AWS S3 Terraform provider issues
I'm trying to create a few private S3 buckets but I keep getting this error
│ Error: Inconsistent dependency lock file
│
│ The following dependency selections recorded in the lock file are inconsistent with the current configuration:
│   - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3: required by this configuration but no version is selected
│
│ To update the locked dependency selections to match a changed configuration, run:
│   terraform init -upgrade

When running terraform init -upgrade I get
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/s3...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 5.0"...
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v5.61.0
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/s3: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which modules are currently depending
│ on hashicorp/s3, run the following command:
│     terraform providers

I only get this error if I add
resource "s3_bucket_public_access_block" "block_public" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.block_public.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

My current providers.tf:
terraform {
 required_providers {
   aws = {
     source  = "hashicorp/aws"
     version = "~> 5.0"
   }
 }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us_east_1_VA"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

There is no resource type named s3_bucket_public_access_block. The first part (the part before the first underscore) of a resource name is the provider. Terraform is looking for a provider named s3 since you declared a resource that starts with s3_.
As you can see from the documentation, the resource type should be aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block. Note how it starts with aws_. All resources in the AWS Terraform provider start with aws_.
